# Do batched documents from the CosmosDBTrigger have a defined order?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am using a `CosmosDBTrigger` to trigger an Azure function like the following example:

```cs
[FunctionName("Func1")]
public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(...)] IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, ILogger log)
{
  // ...
}
```

The code works as expected, however, since I receive the `documents` in batches, I wonder about the order of the documents in the batch. Sadly, I was not able to find an definite answer in the documentation.

My question is whether there is a guaranteed order that can be relied on?
Are the documents in the batch ordered by partitions? By the time they were modified (within an partition or in general)? Or is there no order than can be relied on?

Comment: Are you consuming Cosmos DB Change Feed in your Function?

Comment: Yes, but not directly. I am using the `CosmosDBTrigger` which internally uses the Cosmos DB Change Feed as stated in the documentation mentioned in @Matias Quaranta's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=csharp), Cosmos DB Trigger for Azure Functions consumes the Cosmos DB Change Feed feature.

[Cosmos DB Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) ensures order of events at the partition key value level:

> Sort order of items in change feed
>
> Change feed items come in the order of their modification time. This
> sort order is guaranteed per logical partition key.

Comment: Note that his has now changed to `This sort order is guaranteed per **physical** partition`.

Comment: And now it has changed again and it simply states `This sort order is guaranteed per partition key, and there's no guaranteed order across the partition key values.`